# How do I print the results of a slick query

Tags: scala, slick

I have a table called Materials.  I used slicks schema auto generation to create the TableQuery classes for me.

I can't figure out how to just print the results of a simple query.

```
Materials.map(_.name)
```

I've tried

```
val m = Materials.map(_.name).toString()

println(m)
```

and get the result

```
Rep(Bind)
```

if I try

```
Materials.map(_.name).forEach(m => println(m))
```

I get a compile error

```
value forEach is not a member of slick.lifted.Query[slick.lifted.Rep[Option[String]],Option[String],Seq]
```

To clarify I'm using just slick 3.1.0 not play slick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have written a Query, but it needs converted into an Action by calling its result method

```
val query = materials.map(_.name)
val action = query.result
val results: Future[ Seq[Option[ String ] ]] = db.run( action)
results.foreach( println )
```

The db object needs to be initialized depending the Slick version that you are using . e.g [Slick](http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.1.0/gettingstarted.html) or [Play Slick](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/PlaySlick)

I assume that you have this

```
val materials = TableQuery[Materials]
```

Comment: This gives me a compile error saying it requires slick.dbio.DBIOAction[Seq[String],slick.dbio.NoStream,Nothing] at db.run(action) as the action

Comment: I did not have val Materials = TableQuery[YourMaterialsTableMapping].  The table is named Materials so i used val materials = TableQuery[Materials].  I had to change Future[ Seq[String]] to Future[Seq[Option[String]]] to get this to work but it works now.  Edit your answer to include the Option part and I'll mark it as the answer.

Comment: Edited according your suggestions

Comment: I see this has become a more popular question so I would like to clarify for those comming to this question looking for the answer. I was using slicks schema auto generation to perform this & it was on a demo app I was using to learn scala. I would suggest others that see this question to learn what a scala Future is because that is the result of a slick query execution, but the Seq Option String is not always returned. It will depend. Also a Future is like a monad n printing is a side effect n if you want to do a side effect with a monad you have to use the foreach method to "unpack" it.

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate function with side effects using map:

```
Materials.map(println(_.name))
```